# Prevent closing file in Python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, count

I have a problem reading characters from a file. I have a file called `fst.fasta` and I want to know the number of occurrences of the letters `A` and `T`.

This is the first code sample :

```
f = open("fst.fasta","r")
a = f.read().count("A")

t = f.read().count("T")

print "nbr de A : ", a
print "nbr de T : ", t
```

The result:

```
nbr of A :  255
nbr of T :  0
```

Even if there are `T`s i get always `0`

But after that, I tried this :

```
f = open("fst.fasta","r")
a = f.read().count("A")

f = open("fst.fasta","r")
t = f.read().count("T")

print "nbr de A : ", a
print "nbr de T : ", t
```

This worked! Is there any other way to avoid repeating `f = open("fst.fasta","r")` ?

Comment: make use of variable to store file content like `file_data = f.read()` then you can count chars from `file_data` and avoid reading file twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with the fact that `read()` has a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) (to use the term really loosely): it reads through the file and as it does so sets a pointer to where it is in that file. When it returns you can expect that pointer to be set to the last position. Therefore, executing `read()` again starts from that position and doesn't give you anything back. This is what you want:

```
f = open("fst.fasta","r")
contents = f.read()
a = contents.count("A")
t = contents.count("T")
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) also indicates other ways you can use read:

```
next_value = f.read(1)
if next_value == "":
    # We have reached the end of the file
```

What has happened in the code above is that, instead of getting all the characters in the file, the file handler has only returned 1 character. You could replace `1` with any number, or even a variable to get a certain chunk of the file. The file handler remembers where the above-mentioned pointer is, and you can pick up where you left off. (Note that this is a really good idea for very large files, where reading it all into memory is prohibitive.)

Only once you call `f.close()` does the file handler 'forget' where it is - but it also forgets the file, and you'd have to `open()` it again to start from the beginning.

There are other functions provided (such as `seek()` and `readline()`) that will let you move around a file using different semantics. `f.tell()` will tell you where the pointer is in the file currently.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call `f.read()`, it consumes the entire remaining contents of the file and returns it. You then use that data only to count the `a`s, and then attempt to read the data thats already been used. There are two solutions"
Option 1: Use `f.seek(0)`

```
a = f.read().count("A")
f.seek(0)
t = f.read().count("T")
```

The `f.seek` call sets the psoition of the file back to the beginning.

Option 2. Store the result of `f.read()`:

```
 data = f.read()
 a = data.count("A")
 t = data.count("T")
```

Answer (score 1):

`f.seek(0)` before the second `f.read()` will reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file. Or more sanely, save the result of `f.read()` to a variable, and you can then call `.count` on that variable to your heart's content without rereading the file pointlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `with` construct:

```
with open("fst.fasta","r") as f:
    file_as_string = f.read()
    a = file_as_string.count("A")
    t = file_as_string.count("T")
```

This keeps the file open until you exit the block.

Comment: While this solves the problem, it does so because you saved the contents to a variable; the `with` block keeps it open (per the literal request of the OP), but the OP was really asking "how to I process the contents twice?" which does not require a `with` statement (though a `with` statement is almost always better than not doing so). Without the `with` statement, the file is open even longer, it's just exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Read it into a string:

```
f = open ("fst.fasta")
allLines = f.readlines()
f.close()

# At this point, you are no longer using the file handler.

for line in allLines:
  print (line.count("A"), " ", line.count("T"))
```